# LinAc standing wave

Tags: waves, accelerator-physics

I have a question regarding Linear Accelerators (Linacs):

Originally, traveling HF waves were used to accelerate electrons inside a Linac. You can see a sketch in the following picture. The further the electron beam is accelerated, the longer are the chambers, because the electrons move faster. This sounds reasonable.

[image: Traveling Wave Linac]

However, this results in a very long geometry for the accelerator, so for medical applications, we usually end up using a standing wave accelerator. I was told that for this one we can use chambers of equal length. But I do not understand why this would be possible. The electrons still accelerate, how is it possible that the chambers remain the same size?

Comment: Since Google pulls up many good references, you really haven't tried that hard to figure it out. I will suggest Loew and Talman's 'Elementary Principles of Linear Accelerators', SLAC-PUB-3221 (1983) as a starting point of understanding linacs in general, and the tradeoffs of traveling wave vs standing wave designs.

Comment: The difference between standing wave and travelling wave is just the phase of the RF field in nearby cavities. The (variable) length of the structures doesn't directly enter into this. Indeed one normally gets higher accelerating fields with travelling waves, as the particle can see the maximum field for all the times that it spends into the cavity, while with a standing wave, when it is close to a node, it gets very little acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons have fairly small mass $m_e = 9.11 \times 10^{-31}\,\mathrm{kg} = 0.511\,\mathrm{MeV}/c^2$. Even modest energy beams (a few 10s of MeV) are many times that mass meaning that the electron's speed in the lab frame does not change appreciable when you add more energy (this is a consequence of special relativity).

The speed of a particle is
$$ v = c \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{mc^2}{E} \right)} \,, $$
where $E$ is the *total energy* (kinetic plus mass) of the particle $E = T + mc^2$.

Beam energies are kinetic energies, but when the beam energy is, say, $20\,\mathrm{MeV}$ (nuclear, particle and accelerator physicists routinely drop the $/c^2$ because they work in natural units where $c=1$) the velocity increases little as you increase to a beam energy of $21\,\mathrm{MeV}$. Above about $50\,\mathrm{MeV}$ you can simply ignore the change of the beams speed.

The CEBAF accelerator takes advantage of this effect to accelerate beam components that have cycle from 0 to 4 full times around the machine in the same cavities at the same time.

Comment: I've noted here and there that you tend to use "klystron" in an incorrect way. The word klystron refers to a specific type of high power radio frequency generator (as a magnetron or a solid state amplifier). This radio frequency is then fed to accelerating structures or RF cavities to accelerate the beam. The majority of linear accelerators come with an accelerator tunnel and a separated klystron gallery. The beam never goes directly through a klystron.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. I seem to have been misled by casual use somewhere or another.

Comment: You are welcome! I guess that the confusion may come from the fact internally klystrons employ themselves electron beams to produce the RF, which however are completely separated from the "physics beam" for experiments.